# Why is a synonym appearing in the tag list, with a distinct number of questions?

Tags: support, status-completed, tagging, tag-management

When searching for "trigonometry" or something similar in the [tag list](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags) (or when editing a question), the [trigonometric-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometric-functions) appears, and is said to contain 72 questions:

[image: image of the tag appearing]

But there's a twist: [trigonometric-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometric-functions) is a synonym of [trigonometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometry), which has 10k+ questions, and the following link redirects to [trigonometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometry):

> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometric-functions

What is happening here? Why is the tag appearing in the tag list and when editing questions, and with a different count of questions to boot? Is it the expected behavior?

(I'm asking because I was editing a question involving a trigonometric function, and kept editing the tag [trigonometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometry) back to [trigonometric-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometric-functions), wondering what was happening... In any case it's annoying behavior, and if it's not a bug I'll consider making this into a feature request.)

Comment: The number also appears in the [list of tag synonyms](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms). The column called "renames" is explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190477/what-does-renames-mean-in-the-list-of-tag-synonyms). (Currently 158.) But I am not sure about the number 72

Comment: Maybe the answer here could give an explanation: [Tag Synonym somewhat acting like real tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248113/tag-synonym-somewhat-acting-like-real-tag). Maybe also this is related: [Show total number of questions in synonym group at all occasions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262280/show-total-number-of-questions-in-synonym-group-at-all-occasions).

Comment: Unsurprisingly it seems @Martin is right. The synonym was created, but the tags weren't merged, so [tag:trigonometric-functions] remains on the questions that had it before the synonym was created. It seems that synonym was one of the rare occasions that were created purely from votes of ordinary users. I can't find a meta post where it was suggested. Perhaps it was mentioned in the "Tagging" chatroom?

Comment: [Indeed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24485312#24485312), and it seems [I cast the final vote](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25859472#25859472). So much for the advantages of moderators acting as ordinary users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a tag synonym is created, the synonym remains on the questions tagged with it, unless the tags are merged. In this case, the synonym was [suggested in the "Tagging" chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24485312#24485312), gathered a few upvotes and [lingered on](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=trigonometric-functions&room=3740) until somebody [suggested that I cast the final vote](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25859472#25859472), which I did.

I did however not think of merging the tags then, so [trigonometric-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometric-functions) remained in its half-dead state, impossible to attach to new questions, but remaining where it already was.

The tags have now been merged, so [trigonometric-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometric-functions) won't be suggested any longer.